# Running Wordpress on a subdomain of a URL used for Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, dns

I currently have a Google App Engine application, `myapp`, to which I have assigned a custom domain, `mycustomdomain.com`. `mycustomdomain.com` is currently registered through Google Domains. I set up the custom domain as instructed by Google's docs and it is all working as expected.

Now, I would like to create a subdomain, `blog.mycustomdomain.com` and point it to **my hosting company (i.e. not direct it to my GAE app)**, where I have a self-hosted Wordpress installation.

I have tried doing this through an NS entry for the subdomain `blog` through Google Domains, but this does not work.

Could someone direct me if they know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: So your self-hosted Wordpress is presently accessible by a 3rd party domain name or just by IP address? In other words - do you want just a forwarding to its current domain name or you want to create its first (sub)domain name?

Comment: Right now the self-hosted Wordpress blog isn't associated with any domain name, but I would like it to be a subdomain on the domain that also hosts my Google app. The problem is that if I try to create the subdomain and point it at my host's nameservers, it still ends us directing it to my Google app. It seems that somehow my Google app is overriding any subdomains I set up.